# WebAPI 2 IAuthenticationFilter return 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I need to return 401 Unauthorized from the AuthenticationFiler but when I throw HttpResponseException for some reason it returns 302 Found and then redirects to login.aspx.

Here is my filter example:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Authenticate");

        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and i just register it on Startup.cs

How can I properly return 401 Unauthorized from AuthenticationFiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When implementing authentication filter, you should not throw `HttpResponseException` in case of failed authentication. If you recognize that authentication fails, just set `ErrorResult` property in `HttpAuthenticationContext` parameter passed to the filter:

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("Authenticate");

    context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(Enumerable.Empty<AuthenticationHeaderValue>(), context.Request);
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, exceptions are expensive. You want to keep them to the minimum :)